# Should client protect himself from server bugs

Tags: architecture, protocols, server

I have a general question that related to architecture and protocols between clients and server.
We have a large system that include server and many clients, that system synchronize files between client and server. In the server side we have allot of checks on the input from the client to prevent unexpected behavior.
But our client don't check the messages that come from server  (that check can cause performance issues) 
For example if the server send to client message to delete file, we just delete that file and not make sure (double checking) what is the status on the server (we had a case that that delete send to the clients because of bug in the server side)

so my question is should the client protect himself from server bugs?
If you answer that question please include link for relevant paper/ site.

Just to make it clear all the communication between server and client are protected with https protocol including client certificates so the question is just regarding bugs and not attacks

Thanks

Comment: You mean to say, Server's exceptions details for failing to delete were sent to client?

Comment: I mean that because of bug in the logic level at the server we got order from server to delete some files. but it just one example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for answer I started to read about "Design by contract".
[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) from wikipidia:

```
Contract conditions should never be violated during execution of a bug-free program. Contracts are therefore typically only checked in debug mode during software development. Later at release, the contract checks are disabled to maximize performance.

In many programming languages, contracts are implemented with assert. Asserts are by default compiled away in release mode in C/C++, and similarly deactivated in C#/Java. This effectively eliminates the run-time costs of contracts in release.
```

Also there is a wonderful post about Design by contract [here](http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2013/12/18/code-contracts-is-the-next-coding-practice-you-should-learn-and-use/)

To summarize we need to check for server "bugs" just in debug mode and not in release mode

Answer (score 1):

In general, the server can be a service provided by a 3rd party, like Google Docs, and there you don't have any control.

Even in case I own the server, I would put more effort on alternatives like extensive testing of Server functionality and doing logical delete than physical delete etc. than putting extra hit on performance, but yes that depends on how much are you ready to compromise.

If taking performance hit and maintaining logic at multiple clients is worth than having some important documents deleted and never recovered then you can always make that choice.

PS: I don't have any supporting documents.